# Visual Studio Test Professional 2015 side by side with VS 2015 Community Edition

Tags: visual-studio

I have already installed Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition and using it for my development needs. I want to use Visual Studio Test Professional 2015 to manage my use cases. Can I install the Test Professional side by side on the same machine or will there be any side effects? I am new to the Test Professional, so want to clarify before proceeding.

Thanks